# Using InstaREPL in LightTable on Windows 7 for testing Enlive

Tags: clojure, lighttable

I've been trying to get started with LightTable/Clojure on Windows 7 (64-bit).  If I open a workspace, everything seems to be OK.

But what I want to do is use instaREPL and do some experimenting.  When I start LightTable, open an instaREPL window and type (for example):

```
(require '[net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html])
```

I get the error: java.io.FileNotFoundException.  I assume this is some CLASSPATH issue, but I don't know what the problem is or how to fix it.

How do I get this `require` to work?

Comment: did you try to connect the instaREPL to a repl from a project dir which contains project.clj that specifies enlive in its :dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I cannot use any not 'auto required' namespace (my project dependencies) and I cannot find a answer neither. I just found a workaround to 'mimic' the InstaREPL behaviour on LightTable.

Open 'settings'->'user behaviours' and add `[:editor :lt.objs.editor/on-change :eval-editor]` that will eval the file every time you modify it. The only issue is that you have to 'disconnect' the open connection to the REPL every time you change the project dependencies.

I hope this helps :)